# Hyperlink onclick in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, onclick, telerik

So, I have a Radgrid and multiple controls in it. One of the functionality is to open a PDF once you click on a hyperlink and at the same time insert that clicked value in the database.
I was successful to open a PDF but I am not sure how do I insert this value in the db as I have already used "OnClick" event to open popup window for PDF. Can somebody please guide me in the right way? I have a method with a parameter that inserts the value but how do I call this method when clicked on the hyperlink?

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="GenerateAOC">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="hlGenerateAOC" datanavigateurlfields="ShipmentNumber" Target="AOPLetter" runat="server" DatatextField="ShipmentNumber" Text="GenerateAOC" NavigateUrl='<%# "AdHocAOC.aspx?ShipmentNumber="+Eval("ShipmentNumber")%>' onclick="window.open (this.href, 'AOPLetter', 'height=700,width=700,scrollbars');">
    </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Could you make the database insert it inside `AdHocAOC.aspx.cs`?

Comment: I have a method in the .cs page that inserts in the db but the question is how do i call it on the hyperlink click event and also open the pdf at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using asp.net LinkButton OnClientClick method to open pdf file and then server side OnCommand handler to save data in database. You can pass arguments e.g. Shipment number of the clicked row using CommandArgument

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('<%#AdHocAOC.aspx?ShipmentNumber="+ Eval("ShipmentNumber")%>'); return true;" OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" CommandArgument="<%Eval("ShipmentNumber")%>" CommandName="SavePdfClickDetails" />
```

On server-side

```
void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
      {
         //Here you can save data 
          if(e.CommandName == "SavePdfClickDetails") {
             string shipmentNumber = e.CommandArgument;
          }
      }
```

Check http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/how-to-handle-click-event-of-linkbutton.html

Comment: The OnclientClick event is throwing a parser error and if sort it out then it does not open the page.

Comment: Any JavaScript error in console when you click on the link button?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: Instead of window.open just try console.log or alert to confirm that OnClientClick is working

Comment: Yes, I put OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this slide?');" and yes it works